# How to read a JSON field with @ in it, in ADF?

Tags: json, azure-data-factory

I have a JSON field which starts with `@` (For example `@odata.nextLink`). How can I refer it in ADF. If I try `activity('SomeActivity').output.@odata.nextLink`, it doesn't work.

Note that the field `@odata.nextLink` also has a dot in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the square brackets syntax and remove the dot, eg two examples:

```
@activity('SomeActivity').output['@odata'].nextLink

@activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow['@test']
```

I'm not sure if this is documented anywhere, I just hammered it out.

Comment: Yes, I had figured that out.